# Custom axes labels and legend position in pheatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

I want to put custom axes in `pheatmap` from `pheatmap` package. I tried `xlab="Custom x label"` and `ylab="Custom y label"` but it did not work. I also could not figured out how to change the position of legend.

Minimum working example:

```
library(pheatmap)
# Create test matrix
test = matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10)
test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] = test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] + 3
test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 2
test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 4
colnames(test) = paste("Test", 1:10, sep = "")
rownames(test) = paste("Gene", 1:20, sep = "")

# Draw heatmaps
pheatmap(test)

pheatmap(test, xlab = "Custom x label", ylab = "Custom y label")
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use an alternative heatmap function, e.g. `library(gplots); mypal <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(n = 7, name ="RdYlBu"))); heatmap.2(test, col = "mypal", trace="none", symbreaks=F, symkey=F, xlab = "Custom x label", ylab = "Custom y label")`...

Comment: Thanks @lukeA for your nice suggestion. However, I need to use some functionalities which are only available  in `pheatmap`.

Comment: Waiting might @akrun has some solution.

Comment: These are two independent questions. The first half about the custom x and y labels has been answered here on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538830/x-axis-and-y-axis-labels-in-pheatmap-in-r).