# How to add labels to rows and columns in pheatmap along with row names and column names?

Tags: r, plot, label, heatmap, pheatmap

I am trying to plot a pheatmap. However, unlike other plotting packages in R like ggplot, I am unable to find a option to add row labels and column labels. For example, in ggplot, I can add rowlab using `ylab()` and column label using `xlab()`.
Here is the minimum working example:

```
library(pheatmap)
library(reshape2)

df = data.frame(r = c(1:3), foo = c("a","b", "c"), val = c(5,10,15), stringsAsFactors = F)
heatmat = reshape2::acast(df, foo~r, fill = 0, value.var = "val")

# Create Heatmap
p <- pheatmap(heatmat)
```

The default result is as follows:
[image]
However, I want to have following plot:
[image]

Any suggestions how to add labels in the pheatmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `pheatmap` creates a new page each time you run it. What you can do is like in this post: [x axis and y axis labels in pheatmap in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538830/x-axis-and-y-axis-labels-in-pheatmap-in-r) :

```
library(pheatmap)
library(reshape2)
library(grid)

setHook("grid.newpage", function() pushViewport(viewport(x=1,y=1,width=0.9, height=0.9, name="vp", just=c("right","top"))), action="prepend")
p <- pheatmap(heatmat)
setHook("grid.newpage", NULL, "replace")
grid.text("r", y=0.9, gp=gpar(fontsize=16))
grid.text("foo", x=-0.07, rot=90, gp=gpar(fontsize=16))
```

Output:

[image]

You can change the position and fontsize to whatever you want.

Comment: However, any suggestion to save this plot.

Comment: @Rahi, check this post for saving `pheatmap`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051525/how-to-draw-pheatmap-plot-to-screen-and-also-save-to-file